# ASP. NET Web Api 2 issue - The requested resource does not support HTTP method 'GET'

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am not sure why I am getting a "404  Not Found" on the following GET call to my api (using PostMan)

http://localhost:53840/api/v1/MessageLog/SomeStuff/3

The method in the Controller is as follows

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public string SomeStuff(int s)
    {            
        return "Received input !";            
    }
```

The Register method in the WebApiConfig class has the only route as follows :

```
         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But when I change the code to

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public string SomeStuff()
    {            
        return "Received input !";            
    }
```

The call http://localhost:53840/api/v1/LogMessage/SomeStuff works and POSTMAN displays the "Recieved input !" string in the response body.

Is there a specific calling convention for passing in int/string etc. (I tried using a [FromUri] without much success) ? I have another POST method in the controlled which takes a JObject and that seems to be working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public string SomeStuff(int id)
{            
    return "Received input !";            
}
```

Web API matches the parameter by name. In your route template, it is defined as `{id}` so the action parameter name must match that.

The reason the second one works is because the id is optional and the action matches the template.